# to use RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING for RSA signature

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, digital-signature

Previously I was using rsa signature with no padding ,but now I was asked to add PKCS1_OAEP padding ,Initially I tried simple adding this flag "RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING", but it is giving error code while running like this

```
error:04066076:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_ENCRYPT:unknown padding type
```

Further I googled about the rsa signature with PKCS1_OAEP padding but didn't get anything except it is said that for implementing RSA_PKCS1_OAEP padding you have to use this one

```
int RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_OAEP(unsigned char *to, int tlen,
           unsigned char *f, int fl, unsigned char *p, int pl);
```

and then do private_encrypt with RSA_NO_padding but still having confusion as they have not explained clearly how to use this padding_add function explictly .can anyone provide help .would really appreciate that .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [RFC 3447](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) OAEP padding scheme can be used only with encryption operation and therefore it cannot be used with signatures. If standard RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 scheme is not good enough for you I believe you should use RSASSA-PSS which is recommended for new applications and have characteristics similar to OAEP scheme. See [RFC 3447](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) for more details.

You can easily check out that my answer is correct with command line OpenSSL tool:

1. Generate private key:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
   ```
2. Generate some input data:

   ```
   echo "Hello world" > input.data
   ```
3. Try to generate signature with OAEP scheme:

   ```
   openssl rsautl -sign -oaep -inkey private.key -in input.data -out output.data
   RSA operation error
   139655304349344:error:04066076:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_ENCRYPT:unknown padding type:rsa_eay.c:389:
   ```
4. Try to encrypt data with OAEP scheme:

   ```
   openssl rsautl -encrypt -oaep -inkey private.key -in input.data -out output.data
   ```

You can also take a look at ["rsautl" module source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/rsautl.c) if you need more information but remember that [RFC 3347](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) is your friend :)